# MATLAB save all variables separately

Tags: file-management, matlab, save-as

My current workspace contains 32 variable sequentially named. Each variable is an array of doubles with different lengths. I want to save each of them as a separate .mat file such that name of each file is same as the name of the variable. I could not find any help on google or a previously asked question in SE. Help needed urgently.

Note: I need to associate this data with some other text file that I have for each variable separately. So saving in a single file as a struct is not what I am looking for and the name of the variable should be the name of the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
This simple code below does the trick. Thanks for trying if anyone did.

```
vars=who;
for i=1:length(vars)
save(vars{i},vars{i})
end
```